# How to fill the color on the selected list item

Tags: android

I want to set the colour on list view selected item.I have set the List View item and                       colour like.

```
 { 
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
R.layout.simple_list_item_checkable_1, android.R.id.text1,Data.PERSON));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    View listItem = parent.getChildAt(i);

    if (listItem != null)
    parent.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);  
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);     
    }
      });       
 }
```

Comment: what is error? what is effect of your code?

Comment: You don't say what happens.  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   should this be listItem.setBackgroundColor?

Comment: You can [see here](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="true">
       <shape  >
         <solid android:color="#929292" />
       </shape>
   </item>



   <item>
     <shape  >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
     </shape>
   </item>

 </selector>
```

Use this property `android:state_pressed="true"`, it will make the color for selected item when you pressed on it.

Comment: This code run successfully and I also want to implement click with long click(both state save at the same time)?

Comment: If you want to implement both events in your code, then add long click also. But, how it will be happen, both events are not performed at same time.. then how the states are saved same time??

Comment: If the answer useful to your post, then make it as correct with vote. Then only, it will be useful to the people, who will search for related issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

declare below attribute in XML containing listView.

```
android:listSelector="#AF5c12" // any color code to set color to selected item from list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `listSelector` attribute to set selected item color:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:divider="@null" 
  android:dividerHeight="0dip"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected item color in xml :

```
  <ListView
      android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
  </ListView
```

Answer (score 0):

For minimum API level **11**:
create a selector file with attribute **android:state_activated=true/false**
and set it as background for the list item.
Also include code: **listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);**

For other API levels:
You'll have to create a custom array adapter and add the below method in it.
Initially **selectedPosition = -1;** // this is done to remove selection when the list is loaded for the very first time.

```
public void setseletion(int position) {
   this.selectedPosition = position; // selected position in the list
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In getView() method, apart from setting up the list include this also

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (position == selectedPosition) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.gray));
} else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.transparent));
}
```

Finally include this in the OnItemClickListener of the list view.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {
    MyArrayAdapter adapter = (MyArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    adapter.setseletion(position);
}
```